# Axios then method how to get the text sent from express. Using React Native and Axios

Tags: javascript, react-native, http, axios

I prototyping an app and I cannot get the text sent with the

send method of express

```
    express api sends this.

res.send("monday");
```

my frontend React Native

```
 let ti = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", 
     
                  {
                    
                      celular: celular,
                      senha: senha,
                    
                    },
                    {
                      headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                      }
                    }
              ).then( e => {
               
                Alert.alert(e.status) //ok, status is there
                Alert.alert(e.text())  // how to get the 'monday' text?


              


              })
```

Answer (score 0):

it's 'e.data' I had to look at the response object on the console which is very confusing but I found it.